# Apache Maven 3.5 でDynamoDB downloadエラー

Tags: maven, amazon-dynamodb

EC2の環境にMaven3.5.2 で依存関係を取得で以下のエラーが発生します。
バージョン 1.16.0 はダウンロードでエラーとなりますが、問題がわかりません。

エラー内容

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:jar:1.16.0 is missing, no dependency information available　

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline (default-cli) on project service: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:jar:1.16.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

POM.XML

```
<dependency>
　　<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
　　<artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
　　<version>1.16.0</version>
　　<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/)には登録されていないので、参照するリポジトリを明示する必要が有ります。

`pom.xml`:

```xml
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>dynamodb-local-oregon</id>
      <name>DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

参考:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html